# Capturar dados com Selenium, somar e inserir em outro campo

Tags: javafx, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um código onde ele captura dados de um campo, usando o *Selenium WebDriver* e insere em outro campo.

Gostaria de somar (campo capturado + 1000) e depois inserir em outro campo.

Onde vou inserir + 1000?

```
WebElement ultimokm = driver.findElement(By.id("customfield_23430"));// captura dados no campo
String getultimokmtext = ultimokm.getAttribute("value");
WebElement kmatual = driver.findElement(By.id("customfield_17202"));
kmatual.clear();
kmatual.sendKeys(getultimokmtext);
```